# placing the div below another two different height divs

Tags: html, css

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child1"> 

            </div>
            <div class="child2">

            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">

</div>`
```

I am new to html. In above code,Container is one div and parent div is another div,
the height of child1 is 500px and height of child2 is 300px.

now the problem is,when i am placing parent2 div.It is over ridding child1 by 200px up. i want to display after the container div

Any help!

Comment: please can you add your css for the above code so we can see why it is overlapping.  Also there is no `child2` div

Comment: please give a demo easy to understand your problem

Comment: Not sure if its a typo in the question, but your class 'right' is misspelt. Also if you arent using Floats then your clear is likely going to do nothing. The CSS would help.